# TypeError when importing spCy 3.3.1

Tags: python, typeerror, spacy, pydantic

I am trying to import spaCy version 3.1.1

I am getting the following error when i compile the code

`File "pydantic/main.py", line 121, in init pydantic.main TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'`

> I tried downgrading pydantic version. Currently on pydantic version 1.8.2
> Installed spaCy in a venv. uninstalled and reinstalled both spacy and pydantic.

What should i do?

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/12034

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I tried, but even changing the pydantic version did not help. Tried with 1.10.2 too but same error